# Is it an undefined behavior when you return a ref. to a local variable?

Tags: c++, reference, undefined-behavior

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Returning the address of local or temporary variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744264/returning-the-address-of-local-or-temporary-variable)
>   [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)
>   [return reference to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689030/return-reference-to-local-variable)

Is it an undefined behavior when you return a ref. to a local variable ?

http://ideone.com/Kz381

```
int & func(){

        int x = 10;
        return x;

}

int main() {

        int &y = func();
        cout << y << endl;

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if "local variable" has special meaning in the specification, but I imagine it would be undefined behaviour for any local variable without static storage duration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is. The variable is no longer available when the function ends.

You're unlucky that it appears to work. The thing is, that memory isn't cleared so the `10` is still there, but it can be reclaimed at any time, so it's definitely not safe.

Comment: The very definition of "undefined behavior".

Comment: Do you mean it is ub ! and the y not always print the same result ? and the local variable will be deallocated after the func end !

Comment: Yes it is ub. Yes it does not always print out the same result. The local variable will go out of scope after the function ends, so it can be rewritten with any kinds of crap.

Comment: @faressoft Since it is UB, anything can happen, yes.

Comment: What about this http://ideone.com/ElcLn Is it an UN too ?

Comment: @faressoft yes, it's also UB.

Comment: A comment on the downvote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get technical, returning it isn't undefined behavior. You only get undefined behavior when/if you try to *use* what was returned.